# How do I apply liquibase changesets with question mark symbols in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, character, liquibase

I'm trying to apply a liquibase changeset in `sql` format with valid PostgreSQL syntax. The query contains a `?` operator and a regexp with `?` special character. 
When running this query against DB from `psql` everything works perfect.

When I try to apply this changeset with liquibase, I get an error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Looks like liquibase considers `?` a prepared statement argument and fails. I don't have any prepared statements in my query and I don't want liquibase to transform my query to a prepared statement.

I've found a workaround for a `?` operator (substituting it with double `??` seems to work, though undocumented), but there is no workaround for regexp.

How can I set liquibase to just run the query against my DB as is?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with `'\?'` or **`'{\?\}'`**?

Comment: `?` is a regexp operator, not a literal. I believe operators cannot be escaped.

Comment: So you haven't tried it :(  - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#CHECHCJH

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't work, I think the query gets parsed by Liquibase and it mistakes it as a parameter marker for prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Found help [here](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/174#issuecomment-142068731)

**Reference usage with liquibase**:

```
<changeSet id="1234" author="xyz">
    <sql>
        UPDATE blog
        SET blog__metadata = blog__metadata::JSONB - 'someUnwantedKey',
        WHERE blog__metadata::JSONB ?? 'someUnwantedKey';
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```